# ASP.NET ViewState error?

Tags: asp.net

we recently took over management of a clients site and moved it to a new CMS, it's been a nightmare job and I wish we'd never started!

I had to change a large number of links so for peace of mind I searched for a link checker on the web to make sure all was fine.

I used something called powermapper which didn't discover any link issues but did find the following .net issue.

I am not a .net developer (front end designer)so i don't understand what's being said, I'm hoping  I'm just being paranoid as the site works fine on every browser/system I've checked and my colleague who did the development has recently moved away.

Is the following a serious worry?  Can anyone help to ease my stress!?

Error
This page contains an ASP.NET ViewState larger than 2K. This may cause system instability and blue screens on PCs running IPVNMON.SYS, which is installed by some network monitoring software packages.

Error on 3 pages

source from one of the pages mentioned is as follows - 
Code in head -

```
Dim resourceclass As New resource
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    rssRT.DataSource = resourceclass.ReturnActiveResourceswithLeadImage_ByResType("rev", 1)
    rssRT.DataBind()
End Sub

Protected Sub Repeater_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs)
    Dim rowindex As Integer = CType(e.Item.FindControl("rowindexHF"), HiddenField).Value
    If rowindex = 1 Or rowindex = 3 Or rowindex = 5 Or rowindex = 7 Or rowindex = 9 Or  rowindex = 11 Or rowindex = 13 Or rowindex = 15 Then
        CType(e.Item.FindControl("divPnl"), Panel).CssClass = "press_article float-right"
    Else
        CType(e.Item.FindControl("divPnl"), Panel).CssClass = "press_article float-left"
    End If

    '
    Dim desc As String = CType(e.Item.FindControl("descLT"), Literal).Text
    Dim desclength As Integer = desc.Length
    If desclength > 135 Then
        CType(e.Item.FindControl("descLT"), Literal).Text = "<p>" &   Regex.Replace(desc.Substring(0, 135), "<.*?>", String.Empty) & "</p>"
    End If

End Sub

</script>
```

a snippet of the cody in the body section -

```
   <asp:Image width="477" height="181" Alternativetext="Cranleigh" id="offerIMG"  runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "http://cranleigh.wrd5.com/writedir/images/" &  DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"file_title")%>' />



                </div>

                <div class="press_desc">
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "Reviews-Article.aspx?id=" & DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"res_id")%>' ><img src="images/press_read_more2.png" width="98" height="33" alt="Click here to read more" class="float-right" /></asp:Hyperlink>

                   <asp:Literal ID="descLT" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"res_description")%>' />...
                </div>
            </asp:Panel>

                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Do you have source code access to these pages where this error is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Viewstate is a trick used by ASP.NET to make web pages keep application state between requests, trying to make it looks like a windows application. It's a hidden HTML field on the page where this information is stored.

When developing a web application, developers should using ASP.NET WebForms should be aware of not using this feature too much. Overusing it's a common mistake, and there's a lot of sites on the Internet where this problem can be found. If you have access to the source code, you can ask/hire a developer to rewrite these 3 pages.

If not, you should worry only if your clients have Visual IP InSight (Ipvnmon.sys) installed on their machines.

Comment: Cheers for your help Fabio - the site is for a hotel - so not sure what the visual ip insight thing means or whether it would be an issue?    
I'm only a freelance designer/front-end dev - who's having a huge headache over this horrible site!

Comment: i should point out that nobody has raised this as being an issue (its been live for 4 months) simply me who found that error whilst checking for broken links and I'm hoping its nothing thats going to cause me any more stress!

Comment: I searched for Visual IP InSight, but I didn't find its web site, even inside http://www.flukenetworks.com (former http://www.visualnetworks.com), who looks like to be the owner of it. Maybe this tool is old and it's not used anymore. And I never knew anyone who's using it. Well, I think that should not be something that keeps you awake at night.

Comment: ok Cheers for your help Fabio - much appreciated!  Still leaves me slightly worried though as I dont understand who and how many users would have this insight thing - would it only be old versions of windows!? If its only very minimal users and wouldnt always cause an issue anyhow than my worry is over!

Comment: seems that even microsoft.com displays the same error!  so it mustn't be too much of an issue - worry lessened!  cheers for your help!